# spring.sql.init.data-locations picks random schema

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using spring boot and i want to inizialize DB with some functions inside an init.sql file.
All JPA classed gets created in "myschema" as I want cause of "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=myschema".
My init.sql works too, but on a RANDOM schema and doesn't follow the settings. I can't hardcode the schema on init.sql cause my needs are to be dynamic based on previous default_schema.
I'm loading my init.sql with "spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:fixtures/init.sql"

It's a BUG?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to double define the schema like that:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.schema=YOURSCHEMA
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=YOURSCHEMA
```

One gets used for JPA table creation with a schema, other one gets used by spring init database.